# StoryBoardで作成したUITableViewCellに関連付けたTappedGestureへ、 Cellの情報を渡したい。

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios8, storyboard

## UIGestureでUITableViewのCellをタップしたら、そのタップしたセルの情報を取得し、

## UIGestureのメソッド内にて、メソッドを定義したいのです。

（さらに具体的には、セルの中に画像を埋め込んでおり、その画像の情報を取得し、
そのセルの上にさらにImageViewを表示させ、タップしたセルの情報を保存したいです。）

UITableViewDataSourceで定義されている、セルを返すメソッドですが、、↓

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    return cell
}
```

**tableView: UITableViewとcellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath**の値が取得できればcellの情報は取得できるのですが、、

通常、このメソッド中で処理すれば良いのですが、
StoryBoardからTapped GestureでActionを指定しているので、
それは使えません。

尚、コードでそのcellに関連付けたGestureを関連付けると、
UITableViewが持っているGesture系のイベントとバッティングして反応しないという現象が起こっているのでStoryBoardのcell上のGestureを貼り付けている状態です。

メソッドの引数にtableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPathを追加すればStoryboardから動作しなくなりますし、そもそもメソッドにそれらの引数を追加すれば値が渡ってくるものなのかなという疑問もあります。。。

ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: UITableViewに他の用途でUITapGestureRecognizerを実装しているために通常の方法（didSelectRowAtIndexPath）が使えないということでしょうか？その前提があって、各セルのタップを検出するためにcell内のUIImageViewにUITapGestureRecognizerを実装している、という理解で問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
はい、StoryBoardのcell内のUIImageViewにUITapGestureRecognizerを実装している状態です。
コードにての実装はイベントがぶつかり合うため動作しませんでした。。

Comment: なるほど、だいぶ状況が把握できました。UIImageViewに実装しているUITapGestureRecognizerのactionのメソッドではRecognizerを引数として利用できる状態になっていますか？なっている場合、recognizer.viewでタップジェスチャの発生元のview（この場合UIImageView）が取得できるので、予めcellForRowAtIndexPathで各cellのUIImageViewのtagにindexPath.rowをセットする等しておけば、tagプロパティを介して間接的に行数を取得することができます。

Comment: cellの中で、
imageView.tag = indexPath.row
で設定し、

メソッド内で、
@IBAction func tappedImge(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
var imageView = sender.view.viewWithTag(tag)
}
で取得できるということでしょうか、、

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizerを実装したimageView自体を取得する必要があるのでしたら、sender.viewがそれに該当します。

Comment: 部外者で、しかも別コレクションビュー間のデータ移動という別件ですが、非常に参考になりました。質問者様回答者様、ありがとうございます！
出来れば最後に尻切れた、メモリリークの情報を説明して頂ければ助かります！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントだけでは分かりづらいのでサンプルコードで説明させていただきます。
（説明用のコードのため色々とツッコミどころがあるかもしれませんがご容赦ください）

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let cellImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    cellImageView.tag = indexPath.row

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tappedImge:")
    cellImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    cell.addSubview(cellImageView)

    return cell
}

func tappedImge(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageView = sender.view as UIImageView  //各cellのcellImageViewを取得
    println(imageView.tag)  //行数を利用する必要がある場合はcellImageViewのtagの値を参照
}
```

上記のような形になっているとして、
sender.viewでUITapGestureRecognizerを実装したUIView（cellImageView）が取得でき、
imageView.tagでindexPath.rowの値を取得することが可能です。

Comment: `cellImageView`に、`tapGestureRecognizer`を組み込み済みだったら、再組み込みしないという条件式が必要に思います。そうしないと、メモリリークの原因になるのではありませんか？それと、Swift 1.2(Xcode 6.3)対応か否かの但し書きも必要に思います。